# How can I have an element span 2 or 3 grid columns, depending on the number of columns available?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid container that will contain a number of child elements. You can see the design below.

Since the design is responsive, the number of columns in the container is dynamic, based on width of the container:

```
.container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}
```

This works beautifully - it creates as many columns at least 250px wide as will fit in the container.

The challenge I have is that certain elements (`.wide-child`) should span multiple columns, according to these rules:

- If the container displays 3 or more columns, have the "wide child" span ***exactly*** 3 columns
- If the container displays 2 columns, have the "wide child" span ***exactly*** 2 columns
- If the container only displays 1 column, do not have the "wide child" span any columns (i.e., it should be one column wide).

My first thought was to use this:

```
.wide-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

This works beautifully perfectly when the container displays 3 or more columns.

However, if the container *would otherwise only display 1 or 2 columns,* this rule seems to ***force*** the container to have three columns, which breaks everything.

So, what I think I want is a css rule for the child that says, *"If the container has 3 or more columns, span 3. If it only has 2, span 2. And, if it only has one, don't span any."*

Is that possible?

In the meantime, I've hacked a solution using media queries, but this is a brittle solution, because it depends on hard-coding the exact pixel width that causes the container to show a certain number of columns.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.container div {
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container div.wide-child {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div class="wide-child">Wide child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask] under "Write a title...".

Comment: Not possible to specify a **maximum** number of columns to span. You can always tell the element to span to the *last* column but that's all. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PoVVapv?editors=1100